# Downloading data from Interactive Brokers TWS

Tags: r, api, quantmod, yahoo-finance, interactive-brokers

I have been playing around with the Interactive Brokers TWS and R and I have been having varying success.

```
library(IBrokers)
IBConn <- twsConnect(port = xxxx)
currency_df = twsCurrency("NZD",currency = "USD")
test = reqHistoricalData(IBConn, Contract = currency_df, whatToShow ='BID_ASK', useRTH = "0", barSize = '1 min', duration="1 D", endDateTime = paste0(gsub("-","", reqCurrentTime(IBConn))," EST"))
plot(test$NZD.USD.Close)

library(quantmod)
plot(test$NZD.USD.Close)
chartSeries(test$NZD.USD.Close)
addBBands(n = 20, sd = 2, ma = "SMA", draw = 'bands', on = -1)
```

Which works well, I am able to download 1 minute currency data for that day.

The problem arises when I try to get stock data of a firm

```
tws = twsConnect(port=7497)
symbol = twsSTK("AAPL")
data_AAPL = reqHistoricalData(tws, symbol)
print (data_AAPL)
```

However I do not get the same result as this [blog](https://www.quantinsti.com/blog/using-ibrokers-package-implement-r-interactive-brokers-api/) (**reqHistoricalData Function** - approx halfway down the page).

Other data that I have requested using the following code runs for hours and I am forced to click "stop" in the R console.

```
tws <- twsConnect()
aapl.csv <- file("AAPL.csv", open="w")

# run an infinite-loop ( <C-c> to break )
reqMktData(tws, twsSTK("AAPL"), 
           eventWrapper=eWrapper.MktData.CSV(1), 
           file=aapl.csv)

close(aapl.csv)
close(tws)
```

My question is, how can I download the previous days 1 or 5 minute data for AAPL stock (Open, High, Low, Close) using the Interactive Brokers R package? I can collect daily data using the quantmod package but I am wondering if I can collect minute data using the IBrokers package in the format of Open High Low and Close.

Note: I am using an Interactive Brokers demo trading account.

Comment: As far as I remember, data feed is free for currencies, but to get stock data you need a subscription. Can you observe real time quotes of AAPL using Trader Workstation? What did you get when you called reqHistoricalData for AAPL?

Answer (score 5):

The reason you don’t get the same data as in the blog you mentioned is that you are referring to `historical (i.e. reqHistoricalData(tws, symbol)` data where the example in the blog is referring to `market data ( i.e. reqMktData)` which is streaming and quite different. To get historical intraday data for a stock (AAPL) you must define a `contract` like so:

```
contract = twsContract(0,"AAPL","STK","SMART","ISLAND", "","0.0","USD","","","",NULL,NULL,"0”)
```

example:

```
library(IBrokers)
IBConn <- twsConnect(port = 7497)
contract = twsContract(0,"AAPL","STK","SMART","ISLAND", "","0.0","USD","","","",NULL,NULL,"0")
data_AAPL = reqHistoricalData(IBConn, contract, whatToShow ='BID_ASK', useRTH = "0", barSize = '1 min', duration="1 D", endDateTime = paste0(gsub("-","", reqCurrentTime(IBConn))))


> head(data_AAPL)
                    AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close
2017-10-23 10:00:00    156.00    157.20   156.00     156.64
2017-10-23 10:01:00    155.99    156.65   155.95     156.64
2017-10-23 10:02:00    155.95    156.65   155.95     156.65
2017-10-23 10:03:00    155.95    156.65   155.95     156.65
2017-10-23 10:04:00    155.95    156.60   155.95     156.60
2017-10-23 10:05:00    155.95    156.62   155.95     156.60
                    AAPL.Volume AAPL.WAP AAPL.hasGaps AAPL.Count
2017-10-23 10:00:00          -1       -1            0         -1
2017-10-23 10:01:00          -1       -1            0         -1
2017-10-23 10:02:00          -1       -1            0         -1
2017-10-23 10:03:00          -1       -1            0         -1
2017-10-23 10:04:00          -1       -1            0         -1
2017-10-23 10:05:00          -1       -1            0         -1
```

Don’t forget to close the connection with `twsDisconnect(IBConn)` :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have ran the code that you have and I get head(data_AAPL) with output NULL. I will check if I have a connection error

Comment: Have you checked your port number? Maybe you are runnig your TWS on a different port.